# MSSQL select rows with datetime for each day of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble achieving the results i need in MS Server Management Studio.

I have an SQL table that records process start and end times on a machine and I want to use this data to report on shift performance statistics. The table is shown as below:

[image]

I would like to report on the following statistics per day:

[image]

I can successfully achieve this for a single day using the following code:

```
SELECT 
DATENAME(dw, CAST(PAINTING_END AS DATE)) [Day], 
CAST(PAINTING_END AS DATE) [Date], 
MIN(PAINTING_START) [Start],
MAX(PAINTING_END) [Finish],
DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(PAINTING_START), MAX(PAINTING_START)) as 'Time (m)', 
CAST((CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(PAINTING_START), MAX(PAINTING_START))AS DECIMAL) / 60) * 40 AS INT) as 'Target',
Count(PAINTING_END) [Output],
COUNT(PAINTING_END) * 100 / CAST((CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(PAINTING_START), MAX(PAINTING_START))AS DECIMAL) / 60) * 40 AS INT) as 'Productivity' 
FROM p_statistics
WHERE PAINTING_START >= '2020-07-20 00:00:00' AND PAINTING_END <= '2020-07-20 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY CAST(PAINTING_END AS DATE)
```

However, my goal is to achieve these statistics for each day of a given week between the start and end dates.

I have tried this using the code below but the values I get in my results are incorrect:

```
SELECT 
DATENAME(dw, CAST(PAINTING_END AS DATE)) [Day], 
CAST(PAINTING_END as DATE) [Date], 
MIN(PAINTING_START) [Start],
MAX(PAINTING_END) [Finish], 
DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(PAINTING_START), MAX(PAINTING_START)) as 'Time (m)', 
CAST((CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(PAINTING_START), MAX(PAINTING_START))AS DECIMAL) / 60) * 40 AS INT) as 'Target',
Count(PAINTING_END) [Output],
COUNT(PAINTING_END) * 100 / CAST((CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(PAINTING_START), MAX(PAINTING_START))AS DECIMAL) / 60) * 40 AS INT) as 'Productivity' 
FROM p_statistics
WHERE PAINTING_START between '2020-07-20' AND '2020-07-26' AND PAINTING_END between '2020-07-20' AND '2020-07-26' 
GROUP BY CAST(PAINTING_END as DATE) 
ORDER BY CAST(PAINTING_END as DATE) ASC
```

[image]

You can see that the Start and End times are now incorrect when selecting multiple days.

Can anybody help me achieve my goal?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your 'WHERE' clause logic into a `HAVING` clause. The `WHERE` clause will filter the rows before they have been grouped, but the `HAVING` clause will filter them after the grouping has been applied (This is why I am using `MIN` in the example below.)

Also, I don't think you need to filter out both the start and end dates. Only one date filter should do.

```
SELECT 
DATENAME(dw, CAST(PAINTING_END AS DATE)) [Day], 
CAST(PAINTING_END as DATE) [Date], 
MIN(PAINTING_START) [Start],
MAX(PAINTING_END) [Finish], 
DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(PAINTING_START), MAX(PAINTING_START)) as 'Time (m)', 
CAST((CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(PAINTING_START), MAX(PAINTING_START))AS DECIMAL) / 60) * 40 AS INT) as 'Target',
Count(PAINTING_END) [Output],
COUNT(PAINTING_END) * 100 / CAST((CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(PAINTING_START), MAX(PAINTING_START))AS DECIMAL) / 60) * 40 AS INT) as 'Productivity' 
FROM p_statistics
GROUP BY CAST(PAINTING_END as DATE) 
HAVING MIN(PAINTING_START) between '2020-07-20' AND '2020-07-26'
ORDER BY CAST(PAINTING_END as DATE) ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Jason. Unfortunately this code did not provide the results we need.  Monday's row is missing (i assume because the between section of the HAVING clause starts from the 20th. Also, the Start times shown in the results are from incorrect dates (the day before).

Comment: If you had put data into the post instead of an image, I could have incorporated that into the example, but I wasn't going to type in all that.